# Success Event for Order place on Admin side

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer

I want to know which event is used for firing when an order successfully placed by the admin.

Right know i am using an event `sales_order_save_commit_after`. The problem her i am facing is that while i place an order using a card and the card was not valid or something happened at gateway which resulted in cancel of order. Even if the order is cancel my code still run which shouldn't happen.

So which is the best event for Admin orders in this type of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `events.xml` file here and you can use `checkout_submit_all_after` event there.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="admin_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AdminOrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AdminOrderPlaceAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class AdminOrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/observer.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Backend order placed successfully.');
    }
}
```

This event will work when order successfully placed from Backend.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what is the flow of checkout_submit_all_after

Comment: checkout_submit_all_after event call once your order successfully placed and committed all changed in Database that is related to order. you can check this file **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php** check **saveOrder()** function there in last this event is available.

Comment: In last this event is called when you place any order.

Comment: it helps to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below file in your custom extension

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
            <observer name="sales_order_save_after" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderSaveObserver" />
        </event> 
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderSaveObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class OrderSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        /*
            Write your code here
        */
    }
}
```

You have to access all data from $order object.

**Hope This Will Help You !!!**

Comment: Please explain what is the flow of checkout_submit_all_after